# Why do my camera captures not reflect changes to its properties?

Tags: matlab, camera

This has been a problem I have struggled with for some time: When I change the camera properties, such as Saturation or Exposure, why doesn't it have an effect on the images I capture from the camera unless I use `preview()`?

OS: Windows 7

MATLAB: R2010b

Camera: Microsoft Lifecam Studio

What I tried:

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo',2);
set( vid, 'ReturnedColorSpace', 'rgb' );
set(getselectedsource(vid),'ExposureMode','manual');
set(getselectedsource(vid),'Exposure',-9);
pic = getsnapshot(vid);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to get `getsnapshot()` to work, but the `preview()` would always flicker the old settings as the first frame, almost immediately switching to the new settings.  So you can set the number of frames grabbed on every trigger, then you'd just grab later frames that would have the new settings:

```
set( vid, 'FramesPerTrigger', 2 ); % After setting up camera and its settings
start(vid);
pic = getdata(vid);
stop(vid);
figure,imshow(pic(:,:,:,2));       % The second frame has the new settings applied
```

Grabbing 2 frames and using the second worked for me.  Try later frames if this isn't consistent, just make sure you're grabbing as many as you need through the `FramesPerTrigger` property.